# Can't install SQL server 2008 or SQL Server 2014

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to run the SQL SERVER 2008 setup, it shows the following error and exits:

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal' to type
>   'System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem'.
>
> Error code 0x84B10001.

When I try to install SQL SERVER 2014, it installer doesn't start and it also exits with the following error:

[image: [SQL SERVER 2014 Error][1] (I linked the error image because I don't have enough reps to post images.)]

I have used the SQL SERVER 2008 previously and it worked correctly. But after a windows update today it stopped working and I tried to re-install and it started giving the error mentioned above. As for SQL SERVER 2014, the setup works properly in a friend's PC.

I tried the following resolutions after searching the Internet but none of them worked.

1. I edited the config file at **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\machine.config** by removing the *system.serviceModel* tag and its contents
2. I created an new local user with administrative rights and tried to install the setups from within the new user account.

My OS is Windows 8 Pro(x64)

How can I fix this error? Any help or suggestion is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: As the installation depends on the .NET framework, I suggest trying the [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135).

Comment: I downloaded the tool and run it. But still both setups don't run giving the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install SQL Server 2014 and get this error, use this web site:

http://anewdomain.net/2013/10/21/how-to-enable-net-framework-2-0-and-3-5-in-windows-8-1-for-older-programs/

You should install .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 first. You should check the framework versions on your PC. If you have only 4.5, you will continue to get the same error code.

Anyway, I fixed my trouble.